# How to get SQL Server Profiler to show amended tables

Tags: sql-server, profiler

The ASP.Net application I'm maintaining at the moment has a lot of activity in the database when ever a postback occurs. For the example I'm currently looking at, Profiler shows a mass of activity just to refresh the UI but I know its also updating a couple of tables.

What would be the best trace filter to only show the sprocs/statements that are either inserting, updating, deleting?

Is there a way to just show the table that are I/U/D (but I doubt this is possible)?

Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a trace on SP:Completed and RPC:Completed with column filters on TextData for:

- % insert %
- % delete %
- % update %

Might get the odd spurious result but it'll narrow the field. Add SQL:BatchCompleted if you have a mix of procs and statements.

Comment: Slight change - I removed the space between the first wildcard character and the keyword.